# How to determine which iPhone version the javascript code runs on?

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobile-safari

Need to distinguish between *iPhone3x* and *iPhone4x*. Is there any way to figure out the version from JavaScript please?

Comment: I'd wish not to, but there are some inconsistencies that are not leaving much space for idealistic approach (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298696/losing-text-sharpness-blur-when-scaling-div-over-a-fixed-position-element-on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` to check the OS version, but that isn't really the problem here.

What you can do is use media queries to check the actual screen resolution of the device, which might be the cause of the problem at hand.

```
var isRetina = window.matchMedia("(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)").matches;
```

You could also probably do without JavaScript, by using media queries for loading different stylesheets for retina displays:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="retina.css"
    media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

Comment: Interesting point though: on iOS4 and Rhino the `matchMedia` is better not to be called (some unexpected behavior had been caused and had zero time to debug deeper).

Answer (score 9):

By using WEBGL_debug_renderer_info extension, which is part of the [WebGL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API), you are able to retrieve the vendor of the GPU and the renderer name.

Combining this with screen dimensions of the device you can accurately define which version it is. The code example below shows how you can do this for all iPhone versions including 3 and 4.

```
    // iPhone model checks.
function getiPhoneModel() {
    // Create a canvas element which can be used to retrieve information about the GPU.
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    if (canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        if (context) {
            var info = context.getExtension("WEBGL_debug_renderer_info");
            if (info) {
                var renderer = context.getParameter(info.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);
            }
        }
    }

    // iPhone X
    if ((window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 812 / 375) && (window.devicePixelRatio == 3)) {
        return "iPhone X";
    // iPhone 6+/6s+/7+ and 8+
    } else if ((window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 736 / 414) && (window.devicePixelRatio == 3)) {
        switch (renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPhone 6 Plus, 6s Plus, 7 Plus or 8 Plus";
            case "Apple A8 GPU":
                return "iPhone 6 Plus";
            case "Apple A9 GPU":
                return "iPhone 6s Plus";
            case "Apple A10 GPU":
                return "iPhone 7 Plus";
            case "Apple A11 GPU":
                return "iPhone 8 Plus";
        }
    // iPhone 6+/6s+/7+ and 8+ in zoom mode
    } else if ((window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 667 / 375) && (window.devicePixelRatio == 3)) {
        switch(renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPhone 6 Plus, 6s Plus, 7 Plus or 8 Plus (display zoom)";
            case "Apple A8 GPU":
                return "iPhone 6 Plus (display zoom)";
            case "Apple A9 GPU":
                return "iPhone 6s Plus (display zoom)";
            case "Apple A10 GPU":
                return "iPhone 7 Plus (display zoom)";
            case "Apple A11 GPU":
                return "iPhone 8 Plus (display zoom)";
        }
    // iPhone 6/6s/7 and 8
    } else if ((window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 667 / 375) && (window.devicePixelRatio == 2)) {
        switch(renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPhone 6, 6s, 7 or 8";
            case "Apple A8 GPU":
                return "iPhone 6";
            case "Apple A9 GPU":
                return "iPhone 6s";
            case "Apple A10 GPU":
                return "iPhone 7";
            case "Apple A11 GPU":
                return "iPhone 8";
        }
    // iPhone 5/5C/5s/SE or 6/6s/7 and 8 in zoom mode
    } else if ((window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1.775) && (window.devicePixelRatio == 2)) {
        switch(renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPhone 5, 5C, 5S, SE or 6, 6s, 7 and 8 (display zoom)";
            case "PowerVR SGX 543":
                return "iPhone 5 or 5c";
            case "Apple A7 GPU":
                return "iPhone 5s";
            case "Apple A8 GPU":
                return "iPhone 6 (display zoom)";
            case "Apple A9 GPU":
                return "iPhone SE or 6s (display zoom)";
            case "Apple A10 GPU":
                return "iPhone 7 (display zoom)";
            case "Apple A11 GPU":
                return "iPhone 8 (display zoom)";
        }
    // iPhone 4/4s
    } else if ((window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1.5) && (window.devicePixelRatio == 2)) {
        switch(renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPhone 4 or 4s";
            case "PowerVR SGX 535":
                return "iPhone 4";
            case "PowerVR SGX 543":
                return "iPhone 4s";
        }
    // iPhone 1/3G/3GS
    } else if ((window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1.5) && (window.devicePixelRatio == 1)) {
        switch(renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPhone 1, 3G or 3GS";
            case "ALP0298C05":
                return "iPhone 3GS";
            case "S5L8900":
                return "iPhone 1, 3G";
        }
    } else {
        return "Not an iPhone";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It would be a combination of two methods in Javascript:

```js
function iPhoneVersion() {
  var iHeight = window.screen.height;
  var iWidth = window.screen.width;

  if (iWidth === 414 && iHeight === 896) {
    return "Xmax-Xr";
  }
  else if (iWidth === 375 && iHeight === 812) {
    return "X-Xs";
  }
  else if (iWidth === 320 && iHeight === 480) {
    return "4";
  }
  else if (iWidth === 375 && iHeight === 667) {
    return "6";
  }
  else if (iWidth === 414 && iHeight === 736) {
    return "6+";
  }
  else if (iWidth === 320 && iHeight === 568) {
    return "5";
  }
  else if (iHeight <= 480) {
    return "2-3";
  }
  return 'none';
}

function isIphone() {
  return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
}
```

So all you need to do is test if it's an Iphone and then get the version:

```js
if ( isIphone() && iPhoneVersion() === "6"){
  //code..
}
```

Comment: Martijn Pieters deleted this post citing duplicate answers as unacceptable.  Reposting here only.

Comment: This doesn't work if people select Zoomed on Settings > Display & Brightness > View.

Comment: @trungnnh is right, setting "Zoomed" will change window.screen.width

Answer (score 1):

I came across to a similar problem a while ago. Working on a client's website that had lots of videos loaded via javascript, I found out that the video format they needed to use had a weird frame rate that didn't work on iPhone 3GS -.

Following atornblad's approach, I got to this solution that perfectly suited what I needed:

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    if (!(window.devicePixelRatio > 1)){
        //non retina iphone / ipod
    }
};
```

First it checks if the user is coming to me from an iPod or an iPhone. Then, it checks for Retina support. Since only iPhone 4+ supports it, I managed to call the correct video files for older devices.

Answer (score 0):

Something about the more CPU-speed measuring-methods: They may be an "unfit" approach here, but finding out the computing power of your target device might be useful for some cases.

So here is something I want to add to those methods: instead of counting up a fixed value and measuring the time, it would be more robust to count up for a fixed time and then compare reached values. 
If your user visits you on a device that is much slower, maybe because it runs inside an emulator, he will have to wait until you counted to n. if you had left the loop after, say 200ms, you would just have reaced a very low value, and the UX was not influenced.

Additionally, it's always nice to know, how long an operation will take, it reduces uncertainties.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can check it by taking OS version in query `navigator.appVersion.indexOf("...`
iphone3G has Apple iOS 4.2.1
iphone4 and 4S have  Apple iOS 5.0.1 but iphone3GS has the same.

As variant you can provide cpu speed test by using big loop. Something like `for (var i=0, k=1; i<5000000; i++) k++;` and checkin consumed time for this.

iphone3G(S) has maximum 600 Mhz, and iphone4 has 1 Ghz. So, there is a distinction, and you can to catch it after some tests (loop) and define loop speed for each iphone generation.

But note, all this ways are rough and may have been not correct in other conditions.