# Javascript to detect iPhone 5, ios 8 and Chrome

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript to detect if viewing a page from an Iphone 5 with ios 8 and chrome. I found this but it only detect if it is an iPhone  but not the version or the browser.

```
if(/(iPhone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { 
if(/OS [8]_\d(_\d)? like Mac OS X/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {  
    alert("SI");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to detect this specific device.  It is *far* better to test for specific features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine which iPhone version the javascript code runs on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309998/how-to-determine-which-iphone-version-the-javascript-code-runs-on)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if device is iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: Please spellcheck your question title.