# How to distinguish IPhone 5 and IPhone SE via JS?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, user-agent

Is there any good way to 100% detect if user device is IPhone 5(and not SE). To be correctly i need to know if IOS device model is < than IPhone 6 and != IPhone SE.

Checking CPU speed as i think is not a correct way for device detection.

Comment: "I need to know…", why? Are iPhone 4, 3 and many similar devices OK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine which iPhone version the javascript code runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309998/how-to-determine-which-iphone-version-the-javascript-code-runs-on)

Comment: @RobG Apple pay works on all iphones > 5 and SE. And there is some issues which force me to detect iphone model and not only Apple Pay support.

Comment: You just need to test if `window.ApplePaySession` exists, that's it. See [*Checking for Apple Pay Availability*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/checking_for_apple_pay_availability) Even if detecting the device was reliable, you still can't be sure that Apple Pay is supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to detect support for Apple Pay, then according to the [Apple developer support web site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/checking_for_apple_pay_availability):

> Before displaying an Apple Pay button or creating an Apple Pay
>   session, you must ensure that the Apple Pay JS API is available and
>   enabled on the current device. To check whether the Apple Pay JS API
>   is available in the browser, verify that the window.ApplePaySession
>   class exists:

```
if (window.ApplePaySession) {
   // The Apple Pay JS API is available.
}
```

Comment: I know how to detect ApplePaySupport, also i know some issues with ApplePaySession, iPhone 5 and mark "ApplePay Enabled". The main question is about detecting phone model, i don't need your help with ApplePay, thx.

Comment: @onemantoo—is your strategy is to check for compatible models of iPhone, iPad, Apple Watch, MacBook, etc.? In Japan you'll need iPhone 8, China presents other issues.

Answer (score -2):

You can ask for model name, `iPhone SE` is `iPhone8,4` and `iPhone 5S` are `iPhone6,1` & `iPhone6,2`.

Comment: So _how_ i can do that?

Comment: i am no js expert.

Comment: Even if the device honestly reports its model, the OP still doesn't know if Apple Pay is available or enabled.

Comment: Apple pay is not part of the original question.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary—yes, the OP has added that in comments. It would have been better had they put it in the question.

Comment: @onemantoo have you tried http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings ?